# Network Printer unable to print

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I'm really unsure if this is the right place to ask my question but here goes. (If this is the wrong place, please kindly redirect me to some where more appropriate. Thanks!)

I have a Fuji Xerox DocuCentre-IV C2270 connected on to my network and would like to print documents from my laptop via the Wifi. Upon starting the print job, the document successfully spools but subsequently encounters a Printer Busy error when the printer itself is actually idle. I believe some network error is going on somewhere but I can't figure it out.

The laptop in question here is a Lenovo running on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Any advice/guidance is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I was able to find out how to enable print logging and found this error.

Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational Source: Microsoft-Windows-PrintService Date: 3/10/2015 8:38:05 PM Event ID: 812 Task Category: Executing a file operation Level: Error Keywords: Print Spooler User: Computer: Description: The print spooler failed to delete the file C:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS\00003.SHD, error code 0x5. See the event user data for context information

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Has this laptop ever printed to this printer in the past? Have you properly installed/reinstalled the print drivers? Any information at the Fuji Xerox support site for a solution?

Comment: This laptop specifically, no. But I do have other computers at home which can print to this printer. Drivers seem to be fine though i might try a fresh install again. Can't seem to find anything at the Fuji Xerox site.

Comment: Enable print logging, then try another print job, then go to event viewer and see if it logs any additional details. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784896(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Moab I'm unable to find the setting to enable print logging. The guide says that its only for Windows Server OS. I'm running on windows 7

Comment: I was able to find out how to enable print logging and found this error.

` Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-PrintService
Date:          3/10/2015 8:38:05 PM
Event ID:      812
Task Category: Executing a file operation
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Print Spooler
User:          
Computer:      
Description:
The print spooler failed to delete the file C:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS\00003.SHD, error code 0x5. See the event user data for context information. `

Answer (score 0):

Go to that folder (C:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS) and manually delete that 00003.shd file and any others you find in there. It should print now.

[Source](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-xp-support/1040367.htm)

Comment: I attempted to manually delete the .shd file mentioned. However, upon doing that and restarting the print job, the file respools and generates another .shd file. The same error log occurs in event viewer but with the error code 0x2

Comment: I've noticed that the .spl file has the file size of the spooled file while the .tmp file in the folder reads as 0 kb. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: All files in there need to be deleted. Then restart the PC.